# Why does a select with consistent read from Amazon SimpleDB yield different results?

Tags: amazon-simpledb

I have a domain on SimpleDB and I never delete from it. 
I am doing the following query on it.

```
select count(*) from table_name where last_updated > '2012-09-25';
```

Though I am setting consistent read parameter as true, it is still returning me different results in different executions. As I am not deleting anything from this domain, ideally the results should be in increasing order, but that is not happening.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case correctly, you might be misreading the semantics of the *ConsistentRead* parameter in the context of [Amazon SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/), see [Select](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/SDB_API_Select.html):

> When set to true, ensures that the most recent data is returned. For
>   more information, see [Consistency](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/ConsistencySummary.html)

The phrase *most recent* can admittedly be misleading eventually, but it doesn't address/affect result ordering in any way, rather it means *most recently updated* and *ConsistentRead* guarantees that every update operation preceding your select statement is visible to this select operation already, see the description:

> Amazon SimpleDB keeps multiple copies of each domain. When data is
>   written or updated, all copies of the data are updated. However, **it
>   takes time for the update to propagate to all storage locations.** The
>   **data will eventually be consistent**, but **an immediate read might not
>   show the change**. If eventually consistent reads are not acceptable for
>   your application, use **ConsistentRead**. Although this operation might
>   take longer than a standard read, it **always returns the last updated
>   value.** *[emphasis mine]*

The linked section on [Consistency](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/ConsistencySummary.html) provides more details and an illustration regarding this concept.

### Sort order

To achieve the results you presumably desire, a simple *order by* statement should do the job, e.g.:

```
select * from table_name where last_updated > '2012-09-25' order by last_updated;
```

There are a couple of constraints/subtleties regarding this operation on SimpleDB, so make sure to skim the short documentation of [Sort](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/SortingDataSelect.html) for details.